# Unix - Whitespace at beginning of filename

Tags: linux, unix, grep, removing-whitespace

How can I grep a file which has been named with a whitespace at the beginning of its name and then renamed without the space? By the way, there are other files that include "file1 name in it. The ls - l " File1" will show all files that have the "File1" name in it.

```
$ls -l 
drwxr-xr-x     2 root     root     1515 Apr  8 01:36   File1
drwxr-xr-x     2 root     root     1515 Apr  8 01:49  File1 
drwxr-xr-x     2 root     root     2343 Apr  8 01:54  File3 
drwxr-xr-x     2 root     root     2303 Apr  8 01:59  File4
drwxr-xr-x     2 root     root     2303 Apr  8 01:59  Another_File1
```

As you can see, there is a whitespace at the beginning of " File1". How can I rename " File1" to "Bad_File1"?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com. It's about using Unix, not computer programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quote its name:

```
mv " File1" "Bad_File1"
    ^
```

Also note " File1" is a directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x     2 root     root     1515 Apr  8 01:36   File1
^
```

so what you are seeing with `ls -l " File1"` is the content of such directory.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui. If I do mv, it will rename all the files that have the "file1"name in them.

Comment: No, this is not true. This will just move a specific file called " File1". You can check it by saying `ls -l " File1"` (mind the quotes).

Comment: I did not put the entire list of files but when I do ls -l " File1" I get:
Another_File1
1A_File1
2A_File1....

All the files that have File1 in it as a name.

Comment: Hey, now I see " File1" is not a file but a directory (see your initial question, the line starts with a `d`, meaning directory), so you are seeing the files within that directory. You can check with `ls -ld " File1"`. And use `mv " File1" "Bad_file1"` to rename

Comment: You are totally right. It is a directory. My concern is the mv command to rename just that " File1"

Comment: So read again my original response: `mv " File1" "another_name"`. This will rename the directory name, not the content within it.

Comment: Yes. I went over your comments and tried it. It works great. I'm trying to remember a command that is used to grep whitespaces at the beginning of filenames. I think it uses "\". Thanks again for your quick response.

Comment: Yes, you can also say "ls \ File", since the slash will indicate a special character is coming. However, it is more clear to use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can move all files or directories within a directory that have preceding whitespace to their name without leading whitespace with something similar to:

```
for i in *; do [ "$i" != "${i##* }" ] && mv "$i" "${i##* }"; done
```

It simply uses **parameter expansion/substring extraction** to test whether a file or directory containing leading whitespace exists, then if so, it moves the file or directory to its name without the leading whitespace. You are free to use a `for` or `while IFS=$'\n' read -r line` loop or `find ...` to collect all filenames and preform the test/move. Whatever fits your needs.

**note:** If operating on a directory other than the current directory, you will need to remove/add the `path` component pre/post test in order to accommodate full path.

Comment: Sure, just another way to automate doing the same thing for a entire directory. @fedorqui did all the hard work.